# boost shared_array<char> and set it from char*

Tags: c++, boost

I have a class that constructor takes a parameter `char* name`,then there is a member variable which is `boost::shared_array<char> m_name;`

How to copy that parameter `char*name` to `m_name`?

Comment: Would you like to copy the content stored in `name` or just the pointer itself?

Comment: I want to save a copy of that name.

Comment: This looks like an express ticket to undefined behaviour-ville in more than one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boost::shared_array::get()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm#get).

```
strcpy(m_name.get(), name);
```

Comment: If I want to create a new one,is it safe to do: m_name.get() = new char[strlen(name) + 1] ?

Comment: That will not work, you have to use `reset()` instead: `m_name.reset(new char[strlen(name) + 1]);` then you can use `strcpy(m_name.get(), name);`

Answer (score 1):

FYI, in modern Boost versions, `boost::shared_ptr` supports arrays, so you can use `boost::make_shared` to allocate the array:

```
boost::shared_ptr<char[]> m_name;
m_name = boost::make_shared<char[]>(strlen(name)+1);
```

Then you can copy the contents of `name` into the array:

```
strcpy(m_name.get(), name);
```

```
std::copy(name, name+strlen(name)+1, m_name.get());
```